# Unable to upload large files in azure in chunks through httpUrlConenction without using sdk

Tags: java

```
int totalSize = bytes.length;
            int bytesTransferred = 0;
            int chunkSize = 2000;
            String actualUrl = RequestUtil.expandUri(getApiBaseUri() + url, uriVariables);
            URL urlNew = new URL(actualUrl);
            LOGGER.info("Setting header parameters for create blob details...");
            Map<String, String> headerMap = getCommonHeaderMap();//setting headers by method blob type,url etc.
            LOGGER.info("Successfully set header parameters for create blob details.");
            headerMap.put(HeaderParams.X_MS_BLOB_TYPE, URLConstants.BLOB_TYPES.BLOCKBLOB);
 headerMap.put(HeaderParams.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/octet-stream");
            HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) urlNew.openConnection();

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headerMap.entrySet()) {
                LOGGER.debug(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
                httpCon.setRequestProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
while (bytesTransferred < totalSize) {

            String signature = AccessSignatureGenerator.generateSignatureHashHelper(new URL(actualUrl), HttpMethod.PUT.name(), null, chunkSize, headerMap, storageCredentialsAccountAndKey);//preparing authorization header

            httpCon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "SharedKey accountname:" + signature);

                os=httpCon.getOutputStream();
                int nextChunkSize = totalSize - bytesTransferred;
                if (nextChunkSize > chunkSize) {
                    nextChunkSize = chunkSize;
                }
                os.write(bytes, bytesTransferred, nextChunkSize); // TODO check outcome!
                bytesTransferred += nextChunkSize;


            }
```

how to send chunks with authorization ? What would be the content length? is there any example code...How to send chunks by outputstream of httpUrlConnnection in azure?